# Overlapping absolutely positioned content

Tags: css, css-position

I am having a bit of difficulties with [this page](http://louiswalch.com/beta/t/urs/). It's ALMOST working correctly.

The red box should be centered (h&v) on the window. WORKS.

The yellow box should be affixed to the bottom of the window. WORKS.

**When the window is less then 400 pixels high scroll bars should appear and the yellow box should appear at the bottom of the scroll area.** Basically I never want the yellow box to appear over the red box, or vice-versa. DOESN'T WORK

Anyone know how I can achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the CSS for `#wrapper`:

```
height: 100%;
position: relative;
```

The reason this works is because your absolutely positioned elements are positioned relative to the viewport due to the absence of any other [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details). By adding `position: relative` to the `#wrapper` (or the `body` for that matter) you make sure that the containing block becomes the entire body content instead.

The `height: 100%` is then only needed to ensure that the containing block does at least reach the bottom of the viewport.

Comment: Bingo, this works as intended. Thank you. Doesn't work in IE6, but I don't think that's a huge issue here, if so I can add the min-height hack.

Comment: And actually, do you need the wrapper for anything else? Because given all your current CSS, the `#wrapper` is unnecessary. You could just move all its properties (including the above) to the `body`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#footer{z-index: 1000;}
#logo{z-index: 1001;}
```

Comment: Never want them to be occupy the same space. The footer should be below the logo if the viewport is made smaller then available area.

Answer (score 0):

z-index is what you need. although 1000 is a bit excessive a simple

```
#footer{ z-index:2; }
#logo{ z-index:3; }
```

would do the trick

Answer (score 0):

It's useful to remember that, without specifying `z-index`, the elements stack up with the latest element 'highest' in the z-order. So, if you wanted to avoid specifying `z-index`, reverse the html:

```
<body>


    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="footer">

            This is the footer. It should always appear at the bottom of the page, but not over the red box.            

        </div>

        <div id="logo">
            <h1>Logo</h1>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Otherwise, as the other answer suggest, specifying a greater number for the `#logo` than for the `#footer` will cause `#logo` to be higher.

To enforce scrollbars when the view-port window is < 400px,

```
#wrapper {
min-width: 400px;
min-height: 400px;
overflow: scroll; /* or overflow: auto */
}
```

Comment: As previously stated, changing the z-index will just make the logo appear over the footer. I do not want them to overlap at all. If the viewport is resized to have a height shorter then the two items combined it should show scrollbars and have the footer stacked below the logo.

Comment: overflow: scroll will always display scrollbars whereas auto will detect if scrollbars are necessary (as you probably know), but just clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Z-Index is not a factor here. Z-Index will still allow the elements to overlap - it will only dictate which element is on top.

Use a **float**ing element after the red div in the document flow, and then the use of **clear** on the yellow to create a relationship between the elements (i.e. the yellow div will **clear** the red and will not overlap).

Sandwiching a relatively-sized element (e.g. **height: 100%**) between the two will push the yellow div to the bottom of the screen, but it may be tricky to vertically align properly.