# Issue with main Menu item moving to the right

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created a simple 2 step accordion: http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/36ULG/1/

I am experiences 2 issues:

1) I cant seem to get 'Menu 2' heading to appear directly below 'Menu 1'

2) When i click on 'Menu 2' heading, it moves to the top right

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="heading">   <a>Menu 1</a>

        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <ul>
                    <h2>Top Ten Questions</h2>

                <li>    <a href="">How to reach us</a>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                </li>
                <li>    <a href="">How to email us</a>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                </li>
                <li>    <a href="">Contact Number</a>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="heading">   <a>Menu 2</a>

        </div>
        <div class="content hide">
            <ul>
                    <h2>Products</h2>

                <li>    <a href="">Tabels</a>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                </li>
                <li>    <a href="">Ladders</a>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                </li>
                <li>    <a href="">Chairs</a>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.heading {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 20px;
    background: grey;
    width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 700px) {
    .heading {
        float: left;
        width: 35%;
    }
}
.content {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 700px) {
    .content {
        float: left;
        margin-left: 35%;
        margin-top: -53px;
        width: 65%;
    }
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".heading").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.next(".content").show(400);
    $this.parent().siblings().children().next().hide();
    return false;
});
```

Its important to note that the heading and content need to be below each other when the media queries are triggered on minimizing the browser.

Is some sort of clearfix needed?

Any help appreciated.

**UPDATE** ********************************************

Here's an updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/36ULG/4/ where i have added more Menu items (3 and 4).. Hopefully this should show how the the main menus are not appear below each other.

**UPDATE** ********************************************

Just done some reading on floats and clear, i've added clear: both; to the media query of .heading.. Some minor improvements that some of the Menu items are stacked below eachother, but there is a large gap between Menu's say if Menu 3 is selected you can see the gap to Menu 4. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/36ULG/5/

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/36ULG/2/

Comment: Not sure why this has been upvoted. The solution as you would have noticed the 'content' should appear to the top right

Comment: @DeepakMane - this is pretty much what i have posted. Menu 2 is still appearing in the top right on click and on load not below Menu 1.

Comment: How do you want the menus to respond using media queries? In your fiddle i can see that when the browser width is greater than 700px the width of the heading(grey background) reduces to 35% and when the browser width is less than 700px the heading will take 100% width. Is this how you want this to behave?

Comment: @James - When the browser width is less than 700px, menu heading and the corresponding menu content should be stacked on top of each other (this working). When greater than 700px, all Menu items should appear on the left, and its corresponding content should show on the top right.

Comment: UPDATE ****************************

Just done some reading on floats and clear, i've added clear: both; to the media query of .heading.. Some minor improvements that some of the Menu items are stacked below eachother, but there is a large gap between Menu's say if Menu 3 is selected you can see the gap to Menu 4. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/36ULG/5/ Also, the content doesnt appear at the TOP of the right side.. But in line with its Menu item :(

Comment: The sticky footer is a tricky one to solve. Any solution cannot use `position:absolute` if you want a footer to be pushed down with a long menu. I have added a second demo (see comment on my answer) which might do what you want. If it doesn't then I suggest asking a new question about the footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stacking problem was caused by CSS `float` as the elements are all reflowed around the floated content, causing the heading blocks to appear next to each other. You were correct that you needed to `clear` to ensure the content appears beneath the heading.

@James is correct to add the answer suggesting absolute positioning is required to make the content always appear at the top when width > 700px.

I have also used this in my code but I have also switched to `display:inline-block` instead of `float` since this property does not need clearing, which IMHO results in nicer code.

I have also removed the `.hide` class from the CSS and HTML since the `display:none` was clashing with my new `inline-block`, so I replaced that with a *JavaScript hide* for all but the first `.content`.

Finally, the `<h2>` elements cannot be children of `<ul>` so you need to move them above the `<ul>`. I have also changed that in [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zcPrg/1/).

**JavaScript**

```
$('li:not(:first-child) .content').hide();
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
}
.heading {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 20px;
    background: grey;
}
.content {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    display:inline-block;
}
@media (min-width: 700px) {
    ul {
        position:relative;
    }
    .heading {
        display:inline-block;
        width: 35%;
    }
    .content {
        width: 60%;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:40%;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, this makes a lot of sense and is clear solution. The only problem i am facing (as with James' answer) is that at the bottom of my <ul> is a footer. When the content item is show, in some sceanrios where there are 10 items in content, it is appearing on top of the footer. Hope that makes sense

Comment: I imagine this has something to do with the use of position:absolute;

Comment: Just did a test with position:absolute removed, causes the whole page to expand and not go over the footer (great).. but cause a great gap between the Main menu items (not so great).

Comment: Yes it is the absolute positioning which will cause the problem with the footer. To help with this we would need to see the footer code :-)

Comment: thanks, is there no way that i can surround my <ul> in some form of wrapper DIV with a relative position?

Comment: Similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290877/overlapping-absolutely-positioned-content

Comment: Possibly create a surrounding DIV thats height is determined on the content height?

Comment: I think you need a sticky footer - see http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/ or http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ (better IIRC) but without seeing your code for the footer (and the page in general) I would not be able to give an exact answer.

Comment: Since the sticky footer really should be a new question I have not updated my original answer, but I have built a [**new demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zcPrg/2/) with a proper sticky footer, using CSS [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex). Since `position:absolute` cannot be used I had to dynamically alter the `margin-top` in JavaScript otherwise the menu content would always be at the same level as the menu item, rather than the top.

Answer (score 3):

Check this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/4tq7z/1/)**

When the device width is greater than 700px, position the `ul` `position:relative` and `.content` `position:absolute` so that the content will always align to the fist menu item.

CSS used

```
@media (min-width: 700px) {

    ul{
        position:relative;    
        list-style:none;
        padding-left:0;
    }
    h2{
        margin-top:0;
    }
    .heading {
        float: left;
        width: 35%;
        clear: both;
    }
    .content {
        position:absolute;
        left: 38%;
        width: 65%; 
        top:0;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: thanks, this makes a lot of sense and is clear solution. The only problem i am facing is that at the bottom of my <ul> is a footer. When the content item is show, in some sceanrios where there are 10 items in content, it is appearing on top of the footer. Hope that makes sense

Comment: So when the content is more you want to push the footer down?

Comment: I imagine this has something to do with the use of position:absolute;

Comment: Just did a test with position:absolute removed, causes the whole page to expand and not go over the footer (great).. but cause a great gap between the Main menu items (not so great)

Answer (score 0):

Assign class hide to div .content in first li, instead of second.
Modify the floats and margins for .content and .heading class

```
<ul>
<li>
<div class="heading">   
<a>Menu 1</a>
</div>
<div class="content hide">
<ul>

</ul>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="heading">
<a>Menu 2</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
<ul>

</ul>
</div>
</li>
</ul>


@media (min-width: 700px) {

.heading {
float: none;
width: 35%;
}
}
.content {
padding-top: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 700px) {
.content {
float: none;
margin-left: 0;
margin-top: 0;
width: 65%;
}
}
```